# Environment varaible not being sent from server. Nodejs, express EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable that I have saved in server.js from an .env file. When I console.log() the variable in server.js, it's defined but when I try to do the same from my store.ejs file, I'm told its undefined.

I was able to send an object that I was using to template store items, so that was sent, but the variable was not. 
Here's my code/

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'){
    require('dotenv').config()

}


const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY;
const stripePublickey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY;
console.log(stripePublickey)


const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(3000)

app.get('/store', function(req, res,){
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data){
        if(error){
            res.status(500).end()
            console.log(error, )
        } else {
            res.render('store.ejs', {
                items: JSON.parse(data),
                stripePulickey: 'nut'
            })

        }
    })
})
```

above: server.js
below: store.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Generics | Store</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <script src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" defer></script>
    <script src="store.js" defer></script>


</head>
<body>
    <header class="main-header">
        <nav class="main-nav nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="store.html">STORE</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h1 class="band-name band-name-large">The Generics</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="container content-section">
        <h2 class="section-header">MUSIC</h2>
        <div class="shop-items">
            <% items.music.forEach(function(item){ %>
            <div class="shop-item" data-item-id = "<% item.id %>">
                <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
                <img class="shop-item-image" src="Images/<%= item.imgName %>">
                <div class="shop-item-details">
                    <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }) %><%   console.log(stripePublicKey)%>
```

I don't get why items.json would send but not stripePublicKey. Any help would truly be appreciated.

Comment: You spelled it `stripePulickey` in the response.

Answer (score 0):

spelling mistake. you are passing stripePulickey from server.js but looking for stripePublickey in store.ejs